# org.supercsv.exception.SuperCsvCellProcessorException: the input value should be of type java.lang.String but is java.util.Date

Tags: java, csv, supercsv

I'm using SuperCsv to parse a csv file into Javabeans which I then save in a DB table. I get the following exception when trying to input the date column. After reading the superscv API and documetation I really can't understand how to correctly write a csv to a Javabean and persist the same to a datatbase. The exception:

```
org.supercsv.exception.SuperCsvCellProcessorException: the input value should be of     type java.lang.String but is java.util.Date processor=org.supercsv.cellprocessor.ParseDate context={lineNo=2, rowNo=2, columnNo=3, rowSource=[moredata, 450, Thu Jan 01 00:09:00 PST 2015]}
```

The csv file:

```
someData,23,01/09/2015
moredata,450,01/09/2015
evenMoreData,500,01/09/2015
```

I'm parsing the CSV as follows:

```
private List<Timeseries> readCSVToBean() throws IOException {
    ICsvBeanReader beanReader = null;

    List<Timeseries> timeSeries = new ArrayList<Timeseries>();
    try {
        beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader(pathName),
                CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

        // the name mapping provide the basis for bean setters 
        final String[] nameMapping = new String[]{"varval", "actualNum", "daterec"};
        //just read the header, so that it don't get mapped to Timeseries object
        final String[] header = beanReader.getHeader(false);
        final CellProcessor[] processors = getProcessors();

        Timeseries timeEntity;

        while ((timeEntity = beanReader.read(Timeseries.class, nameMapping,
                processors)) != null) {
            timeSeries.add(timeEntity);
        }

    } finally {
        if (beanReader != null) {
            beanReader.close();
        }
    }
    return timeSeries;
}

private static CellProcessor[] getProcessors() {

    final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[]{
        new NotNull(), // varval
        new ParseInt(), // actualNum
        //new FmtDate("dd/MM/yyyy") 
        new ParseDate("dd/mm/yyyy") // Daterec
    };
    return processors;
}
```

The `Timeseries` bean is:

```
public class Timeseries implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer timid;
    private String varval;
    private Integer actualnum;
    private Date daterec;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented on the Super CSV [website](http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/cell_processors.html), `ParseDate` is used for reading (`String` -> `Date`) and `FmtDate` is used for writing (`Date` -> `String`).

You'll need one set of processors for reading, and another for writing.